# Is this an optimisation bug?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, assembly

Here is some output from my compiler in assembler. It's the MPLAB C30 C compiler, based on GCC v3.23, for a dsPIC33FJ128GP802, a 16-bit moderately high speed DSP/MCU.

```
212:               inline uint16_t ror_16(uint16_t word, int num)
213:               {
 078C4  608270     and.w w1,#16,w4
 078C6  DE0204     lsr w0,w4,w4
 078C8  780101     mov.w w1,w2
 078CA  EA8102     com.w w2,w2
 078CC  EA8183     com.w w3,w3
 078CE  610170     and.w w2,#16,w2
 078D0  DD0002     sl w0,w2,w0
 078D2  700004     ior.w w0,w4,w0
214:                num &= 16; // limit to 16 shifts
215:                return (word >> num) | (word << (16 - num));
216:               }
 078D4  060000     return
```

In particular I'm interested in the following:

```
and.w w1,#16,w4         AND W1 with 16, storing result in W4
lsr w0,w4,w4            Logical shift right W0 by W4 times storing result in W4
mov.w w1,w2             Move W1 to W2
com.w w2,w2             Logical complement of W2 stored in W2
com.w w3,w3             Logical complement of W3 stored in W3   <-- This line is confusing me
and.w w2,#16,w2         AND W2 with 16, storing result in W2
sl w0,w2,w0             (Logical) shift left W0 left by W2 times storing result in W0
ior.w w0,w4,w0          Inclusive OR of W0 and W4 stored in W0
return                  Return from function
```

W0..W15 are an array of sixteen on chip 16-bit registers.

Effectively this simplifies to (in a primitive RTL):

```
W4 := W1 & 16
W4 := W0 LSR W4
W1 := W2
W2 := COM W2
W3 := COM W3
W2 := W2 & 16
W0 := W0 SL W2
W0 := W0 | W4
return
```

Now I'm confused at why it is computing the complement of W3 when there are only two passed arguments (W0 and W1 - it uses the W array for passing arguments to functions for functions with smaller arguments.) W3 is never used in the calculation, and is never returned. In fact it doesn't even appear to have data in it: nothing is stored in it by the function, and only the callee will have some data in it (although functions are not required to preserve W0..W7 so the callee should not be relying on it.) Why is it included in the code? Is it just a compiler glitch or error, or am I missing something?

And it's not just this code - I'm seeing the very same oddness in other parts of code. Even code designed to calculate things like complements of a 16-bit variable always seem to use two registers. It has me lost!

Comment: This could be a quirk in the design of the instruction set. Perhaps the pipeline works in such a way that you should always have executed another `COM` instruction before using the results of the previous one.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq No such pipeline on this processor. Maybe it has a two stage pipeline (so it can operate the fetch-decode-execute-write RISC cycle), but it's not dependent on previous instructions. Its only latencies come from branches and instruction skips.

Comment: Can you post the original C code of the function? Shift by 16 of an 16bit register looks really odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not coded to limit the count to 16 (which I suspect you mean 0 to 16) but limits it to 0 or 16.

Instead of

```
num &= 16
```

you perhaps want

```
num > 16 ? (num & 15) : num
```

Re: the question, since the function is inlined, it can only be answered by looking at where it is used. Perhaps W3 is used for something in the surrounding code. Or it could be a "bug," but one that only has performance, not correctness, impact.

If num can be only 0 or 16 (as in your code) then (16 - num) can also only be 16 or 0, which is why C30 can do the "subtract" with a complement and mask.

FYI, when I don't inline, in C30 I get:

```
34:                uint16_t ror_16(uint16_t word, int num)
35:                {
 05AF4  608170     and.w 0x0002,#16,0x0004
 05AF6  DE0102     lsr 0x0000,0x0004,0x0004
 05AF8  EA8081     com.w 0x0002,0x0002
 05AFA  6080F0     and.w 0x0002,#16,0x0002
 05AFC  DD0001     sl 0x0000,0x0002,0x0000
 05AFE  700002     ior.w 0x0000,0x0004,0x0000
36:                    num &= 16; // limit to 16 shifts
37:                    return (word >> num) | (word << (16 - num));
38:                }
 05B00  060000     return
```

I might code this as

```
34:                uint16_t ror_16(uint16_t word, int num)
35:                {
 05AF4  780100     mov.w 0x0000,0x0004
36:                    num &= 15; // mod 16
 05AF6  60806F     and.w 0x0002,#15,0x0000
37:                    return (num == 0) ? word : ((word >> num) | (word << (16 - num)));
 05AF8  320004     bra z, 0x005b02
 05AFA  DE1080     lsr 0x0004,0x0000,0x0002
 05AFC  100070     subr.w 0x0000,#16,0x0000
 05AFE  DD1000     sl 0x0004,0x0000,0x0000
 05B00  708100     ior.w 0x0002,0x0000,0x0004
38:                }
 05B02  780002     mov.w 0x0004,0x0000
 05B04  060000     return
```

Comment: No, it is a fast way of computing the modulo. As the processor would reset if the number is greater than 16 I think. And while this might cause incorrect data, but it won't reset/crash the processor. W3 is used in surrounding code, but does not have a fixed purpose; see my question for details. And I fear the compiler ignores the inline instruction. The code is the same with and without it.

Comment: you can get a fast modulo 16 with &= 15, but you want modulo 17 which cannot be done with &; however, since rotate by 16 is the same as rotate by 0, &= 15 is actually what you probably want.

Comment: Perhaps your compiler is newer and has a bug fix. Which version are you using?

Comment: Language tool versions: pic30-as.exe v3.24, pic30-gcc.exe v3.24, pic30-ld.exe v3.24, pic30-ar.exe v3.24

Comment: @Doug Currie, I have v3.23, so I am one version behind it seems. Might want to upgrade soon then.